# How to compute focal lenght of a camera from KITTI dataset

Tags: python, vision, kitti

I work on the Kitti dataset of stereo images. 
I have the intrinsic matrix given:

```
K_l = np.array([9.597910e+02, 0.000000e+00, 6.960217e+02, 0.000000e+00,
                9.569251e+02, 2.241806e+02, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00])
```

How can I compute the focal length from this matrix?

We know that this matrix has the expression:

```
cam.K =     [ -f/d   0    Cx;
                0  -f/d   Cy;
                0    0     1];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the camera matrix `f` is normally expressed in pixels, so you must multiply it by a coefficient to retrieve real world coordinates:

Fx = fx * W / w

with:

- W: sensor width in world coordinates (meters)
- w: sensor width in pixels (number of pixels in a row)

Those informations are available on the camera specs.